# Constantly receiving "The network connection was lost" from Google Cloud Storage API on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to upload an image using Google Cloud Storage REST API and I constantly receive following error:
`NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost."`

```
        var components = URLComponents(string: "https://storage.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/\(bucketName)/o")!
        components.queryItems = [
            URLQueryItem(name: "uploadItem", value: "media"),
            URLQueryItem(name: "name", value: filename)
        ]
        
        var request = URLRequest(url: components.url!)
        request.setValue("Authorization", forHTTPHeaderField: "Bearer \(accessToken)")
        request.setValue("image/jpeg", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        
        let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.upload(for: request, from: try! Data(contentsOf: fileURL))
        if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
            print("Status code:", httpResponse.statusCode)
            print("Response:", String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) ?? "")
        }
```

Interesting thing is that using other languages like Kotlin, I have no errors and file is uploaded correctly.

```
val contentType = "image/jpeg".toMediaType()
val requestBody = file.asRequestBody(contentType)
val request = Request.Builder()
    .url("https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/${BUCKET_NAME}/o?uploadType=media&name=$fileName")
    .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer $accessToken")
    .post(requestBody)
    .build()
val client = OkHttpClient()
val response = client.newCall(request).execute()
```

Comment: i think u have to change the value and the field name like this ```request.setValue("Bearer \(accessToken)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")```

Comment: OMG that's so embarrassing... you're correct. It solved the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a small error in your code. You have to have swapped the header name and value.

Replace the following line

`request.setValue("Authorization", forHTTPHeaderField: "Bearer \(accessToken)")`

with

`request.setValue("Bearer \(accessToken)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")`

Comment: Wow man, a year later stumbled into this as well, thanks!